# How to make a 404 not a failure

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to make a ajax call 404 result not a error! something like

```
if(xhr.status == 404){
    //This is not a error ajax! dont treat it as such!
}
else{
    //Ok this is a error... go KABUM on the user!
}
```

Comment: Instead of redirecting to 404 page, write some code within the if statement(not wise).

Comment: Stop returning a 404 from the server. A 404 is an ***error*** so the only way to *not* make it an error is to return something else.

Answer (score 0):

There are to ways to handle ajax errors.

the first one global:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings, exception) {
    if(xhr.status==404) {
    }
});
```

and the second one:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        if(xhr.status==404) {
        }            
    }
});
```

Comment: they are still errors! i need to tell ajax that result 404 is not a error!

Comment: It seems that it's not possible. The logging errors in console is a behavior of browser when any HTTP request is handled.